# Is there an OS that allows the same name for files in the same folder?

Tags: operating-systems, filenames

Is there an OS that allows the same name for files in the same folder?

By "same name", I mean absolutely identical, including the extension.

Comment: I doubt any such system exist... how would files be distinguished? using inodes alone? then file names are completely irrelevant if so...

Comment: @WaleedHamra I can imagine complicated system that uses file size to distinguish files, for example. Anyway files have some other ID then names

Comment: yes, inodes... file names are just a human-readable mapping to these inodes, but if a system is to rely solely on them to distinguish between files, then filenames are completely irrelevant to the system.

Comment: While it may be possible in principle, no filesystem I know of permits it.

Comment: There have been file systems (and apparently Windoze is reviving this to a degree) where files were "versioned", so you could write to the same file name N times and then go back and ask for an earlier version.  And, of course, some tape file schemes permitted this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VMS](http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/731final/4506/4506pro_015.html) allows for identical file names in a directory. You can incorporate a 5 digit version number after identical names and extensions - so you have a great deal of latitude storing many, many, many identically named files on that OS/filesystem without needing to hack or modify it.

It's not clear how this will help you or what problem you are solving, but what you ask has been coded on production OS before.

Comment: if the version number is counted then [NTFS](https://www.howtogeek.com/56891/use-windows-7s-previous-versions-to-go-back-in-time-and-save-your-files/) and [many modern filesystems can do that also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3195160/995714)